# Bazaar cannot break lock

Tags: bazaar

I'm getting the following message after closing window displayed after `bzr qlog`:

```
Unable to obtain lock file:///home2/amadeuszs/.bazaar/lock held by Amadeusz on heh (process #21462), acquired 171 hours, 32 minutes ago.
Will continue to try until 11:24:11, unless you press Ctrl-C.
See "bzr help break-lock" for more.
```

I tried `bzr break-lock` but with no effect. Has anyone have any idea how to break that lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don`t know when, or why bazaar created this lock. If you want to remove it, you can just delete /home2/amadeuszs/.bazaar/lock, for example using:

`rm -rf /home2/amadeuszs/.bazaar/lock`